# Unsuccessful installation of php56w-common on CentOS 6.9

Tags: centos, php-5.6

Whenever try to install, the server throws this error;

```
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-xml
           Removing: php56w-xml-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-xml = 5.6.31-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-xml-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-xml-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-xml = 5.6.40-1.w6
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-pcre
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-pcre
           Obsoleted By: php-common-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-pcre
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-zlib
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-zlib
           Obsoleted By: php-common-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-zlib
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-ftp
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-ftp
           Obsoleted By: php-common-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-ftp
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-tokenizer
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-tokenizer
           Obsoleted By: php-common-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-tokenizer
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-cli
           Removing: php56w-cli-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-cli = 5.6.31-1.w6
           Obsoleted By: php-cli-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-cli-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-cli = 5.6.40-1.w6
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-bz2
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-bz2
           Obsoleted By: php-common-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-common-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-bz2
Error: Package: 1:php56w-pear-1.10.4-1.w6.noarch (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-posix
           Removing: php56w-process-5.6.31-1.w6.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-posix
           Obsoleted By: php-process-7.0.33-20.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
               Not found
           Updated By: php56w-process-5.6.40-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php56w-posix
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
webmin-1.941-1.noarch has missing requires of unzip
.. install failed!
```

And while trying to update "php56w-common" the whole bunch of below mentioned libs as well listed in the control panel.

```
Building complete list of packages ...

php56w-common   5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Common files for PHP
php56w-cli  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Command-line interface for PHP
php56w-process  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php56w-xml  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 A module for PHP applications which use XML
php56w-cli  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Command-line interface for PHP
php56w-common   5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Common files for PHP
php56w-process  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php56w-xml  5.6.31-1.w6 5.6.40-1.w6 A module for PHP applications which use XML
```

I would appreciate any input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix various providers for PHP stack (*remi* + *webtatic*)

**Notice**: PHP 5.6 have reached its EOL in January 2019, so I heartily recommend to use a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

I also recommend to not use *webtatic* repository which seems [dead](https://github.com/webtatic-rpms) (no change since October 2019)

```
yum-config-manager --disable webtatic
```

If you really need [PHP 5.6](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/02/07/PHP-5.6-is-dead), you can install it from *remi*'s repository, see the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) for proper instruction.